# Join Rapidminer

Tags: join, rapidminer

I have two data sets in excel that I want to join but with a major twist. Here is how my data looks like:

[image]

Please notice a couple of things:
1- for ID 3 the phone in sheet1 is different than in sheet2; 
2- for ID 4 there is phone number in sheet2 but none in sheet1

What I want is a combination of those 2 sheets that will contain all the information. Thus, the missing values will be filled and whenever there are 2 different values for the same ID I want rapidminer to create an additional column that contains the other value (for example: phonenumber1, phonenumber2).

Note I am not a very technical person thus let me know if there is a simple solution and if it was complex explain the steps that I need to do in detail.

THX!

Answer (score 1):

The `Join` operator will do what you want if you set its parameters correctly. Firstly, after you have read in your spreadsheets, connect both example sets to the `Join` operator. Set the `key attributes` of this operator to be `ID` and `age` for both the left and right keys. Next, clear the `remove double attributes` parameter.

After you run the process, you should see additional columns.